# Решение арифметического примера, ошибка, ASM

Tags: ассемблер

```
stk segment stack 'stack'
db 256 dup('?')
stk ends
data segment 'data'
A db 10
B db 4
C dw -23
D dw ?
E dw ?
F dd ?
data ends
code segment 'code'
assume cs:code, ds:data, ss:stk
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov ax,C
imul C
mov bl,A
mov bh,0
sub ax,bx
imul ax
mov word ptr F,dx
mov word ptr [F+4],ax
imul C
mov E,ax
mov ah,B
add E,ax
mov ax,D
idiv E
mov D,ax
sub D,20
mov dl,al
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h
mov ah,4Ch
int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Ошибка при написании кода для решения уравнения

```
x= ((d^2 - a)^2)/(d^2 +b))-20, при a=10, b=4, d=-23
```

Где она?

Comment: О боже, `int 21h`!

А вы под отладчиком проходить пробовали? А то отладка ассемблера «в голове» — занятие непростое.

Comment: Несколько замечаний:

1. Назовите переменные своими именами (в условии у вас даны a,b,d, ответ в x, в коде даны a,b,c, ответ в d, плюс две вспомогательные переменные). Если где-то храните квадрат d, то так и назовите d_squared, накрайняк d_v_kvadrate. Ну и т.д.
2. Переносами строк разбейте код на смысловые блоки, так будет намного более читаемо.
3. Откомментируйте код, просто для себя.
4. В конце концов, пройдитесь отладчиком.

Answer (score 1):

Переписал полностью с нуля для fasm под Windows, но с использованием 16-битных регистров в вычислениях. Это требует некоторой аккуратности, т.к. при возведении в квадрат при вычислении делимого происходит выход за 16 бит, результат возведения в степень помещается в `dx:ax`. На каждом этапе для контроля делал отладочный вывод (сейчас закомментирован).

```
; x= ((d^2 - a)^2)/(d^2 + b))-20, при a=10, b=4, d=-23

format PE console
include 'win32ax.inc'

entry start

section '.data' data readable writeable
    A dw 10
    B dw 4
    D dw -23

    _fmt db '%d',13,10,0

    D2 dw ?
    divider dw ?

section '.code' code readable executable
start:
    ; D2 = D * D
    mov ax, [D]
    imul ax
    mov [D2], ax

    ; movsx eax, ax
    ; cinvoke printf, _fmt, eax
    ; mov ax, [D2]

    ; (D^2 + B) ; В данном случае удобнее считать сначала делитель
    add ax, [B]
    mov [divider], ax

    ; movsx eax, ax
    ; cinvoke printf, _fmt, eax

    ; (D^2 - A)^2
    mov ax, [D2]
    sub ax, [A]
    imul ax ; результат в dx:ax

    ; push dx
    ; push ax
    ; shl edx, 16
    ; mov dx, ax
    ; cinvoke printf, _fmt, edx
    ; pop ax
    ; pop dx

    idiv [divider] ; делимое в dx:ax, результат в ax

    ; push ax
    ; movsx eax, ax
    ; cinvoke printf, _fmt, eax
    ; pop ax

    sub ax, 20

    movsx eax, ax
    cinvoke printf, _fmt, eax

    invoke getch
    invoke ExitProcess

section '.idata' import data readable

library kernel, 'kernel32.dll', \
        msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'

import kernel,\
        ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'

import msvcrt,\
        printf,'printf',\
        getch,'_getch'
```

В результате получается 485. Для проверки, вот код на python:

```py
a=10
b=4
d=-23
x=((d**2-a)**2)//(d**2+b)-20
print(x)
```

Вывод: 485